# Symfony 1.4: Check if form has errors inside form class

Tags: forms, validation, symfony1, symfony-1.4

Is there a simple way in Symfony 1.4 to know whether a submitted form had any errors inside the form class? I'm familiar with the `$form['some_field']->hasErrors()` for templates but in this case I'd like to run a post-validator only if the form didn't have any errors with the standard validators. I'm basically after something like:

```
public function configure() {

  // widgets

  // standard validators

  if (!this->hasErrors()) {
    // run post-validator
  }

}
```

The API documentation is as cryptic as usual. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the validation is perfom on the `bind` call, I don't see other place to *post validate on error* than in the `bind` function. So, in your form class:

```
public function bind(array $taintedValues = null, array $taintedFiles = null)
{
  parent::bind($taintedValues, $taintedFiles);

  if ($this->hasErrors())
  {
    // do post validate
    // you can access values from your form using $taintedValues
  }
}
```

But you will have to manually call the validator instead of just define a new one (since the bind process has already been done).